# How to do a databse polling in wso2 mediator?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I would like to make a database polling in wso2 mediator, but it seems there is no mediator ready to do that.

My problem is that I have tried to make a listener task with a dblookup but I have combined more than 10 mediators and it seems that it is not the best way.
What I need to do is: listen to a field in the databse, when the field is changed, I will fire an external webservice.

Should I create a custom mediator for polling or are there ready mediators?
wso2 docs are not enough to complete my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you'll need your 10 mediators. My approach would be like this

1.) store the actual value of the field in a database (e.g. internal H2 database) using dbreport mediator (https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/DB+Report+Mediator)

2.) create a scheduled task that triggers your proxy

3.) create a proxy that retrieves the value from the database where you stored the last value, use dblookup mediator (https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/DBLookup+Mediator) to retrieve the actual value from your database. If the values are different do something using filter mediator and update the value in your local db (https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Filter+Mediator)

My approach depends on how fast the value in the db changes. If there's a high frequency I assume this will not work properly.

Comment: thank you, Martin, it works fine, but it causes lots of hits to my database.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using DB listener inbound with WSO2 ESB? This solves your problem.

[1] https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/esbconnector/details/da8c396a-281e-493b-87bc-b55a4cebe92d

Best Regards,
Malaka